# How to get the system folder?

Tags: .net, system, directory

I'm planning a program that can add URL strings to the 'hosts' file found in the system/drivers/etc directory in order to prevent the user from accessing websites they aren't permitted to.

I was just wondering how to refer to a specific system folder, like the one below, in a way that would avoid hard coding the English names for the folders.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

I'm aware that you can use this to get the first bit (up to System32), but how would I create a universal reference to the 'etc' folder? I don't know if either 'driver' or 'etc' are present on a French or Spanish OS, say.

```
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
```

This question also extends to referencing the 'hosts' file in the 'etc' folder (how on earth does one ensure this is cross-linguistically compatible?). I'd really appreciate your help with this conundrum, I imagine I'm just not seeing the obvious...

Thanks

Will

Comment: This looks like a .NET call?

Comment: The folder names of the operating system won't change with user language. It is safe to assume that it will always be located in /drivers/etc/.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be concerned about the directory structure inside the system folder, it's fixed. Just [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) the system folder with `driver` and `etc`.